# iOS web app opens Safari in spite of avoiding HTML 'href' links

Tags: ios, safari

My IOS (tested on 9.2) web application (apple-mobile-web-app-capable) avoids `<a href="xxx" />`
links and uses only Javascript navigation functions like `windows.location.replace(url)` to navigate to the pages.

The root of my application is not **www.xxx.com** but **www.xxx.com/mysite**. Some of the navigate operations to */mysite/xxx* are working, but other navigations to */mysite/yyy* open the Safari window. 
Beside the `<a href="xxx" />` links, are there other situations which can cause the web app to open the link in a separate Safari window ?

I do not use `target` Attribute. All my links look like

```
<a ng-click="vm.replace('/mysite/xxx') class="navbar-brand">Contact</a>

...

replace(url:string) {
    this.$window.location.replace(url);
}
```

I also tried the different variations (`location.href = url`, `location = url`) all with same result. Maybe the Problem is IOS 9.2 related, I am sure that the same construct was working in web apps I created some month ago.
 
Is it possible that the content of the target page is responsible for this behavior ? Navigating from */mysite/Home* to to */mysite/Media* works, navigating to */mysite/EPG* opens the Safari browser. 
Maybe something bad in the browser cache ? So I cleared the cache, but same result.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it sounds like `target="_blank"` is being used, which is what causes web links to open in a new window. As you're using JavaScript for all your links, this should be relatively easy to check.

Comment: I did not use target attribute. I added some more info to my question.

Comment: I just read the update you posted, and I agree this seems puzzling – particularly because you've said it worked fine before. My understanding of `replace()` is that it makes the back button unusable. I wonder whether Safari is trying to "fix" what it considers bad practice. Does `assign()` work any better?

Comment: I tried any variation ('location = url, location.href = url, location.assign(url) and location.replace(url)'). They all have the same behavior. I am sure that some month ago (before iOS9) I used 'replace()' in another app and it was OK. The crazy thing now is that it works for _/mysite/Media_ but not for  _/mysite/EPG_. I also tried cleaning browser cache. Is it possible, that the content of the target page causes opening in Safari ? But there is nothing special inside ...

Comment: I think it's safe to say that my answer + comment haven't helped, so I'm afraid you'll need to wait for someone else to jump in – sorry!